# Keep getting the Warning 4996, even after defining _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Tags: c++, warnings, preprocessor

Hi I'm been struggling to get my preprocessor to quit bugging me about this:

So I added `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in the `C/C++ -> preprocessor -> definitions`

But it still said the same, so I defined it below as shown in the code below.
though it didnt work. It is shown in output as an error though and not a warning. Is there anything else I should do?

```
#include "texture.h"
#include <iostream>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stb_image.h"
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

Texture::Texture(const std::string& fileName)
{
    int width, height, numComponents;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load((fileName).c_str(), &width, &height, 
    &numComponents, 4);

   //rest isnt really neccesary i guess
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the very beginning of the program:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  FILE *f = fopen("a", "r");
}
```

But following compiles with the warning because `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` comes after `#include <iostream>`:

```
#include <iostream>

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main()
{
  FILE *f = fopen("a", "r");
}
```

The same for `#pragma warning(disable: 4996)`, you need to put it at the beginning of the program (or at least before `#include <iostream>`)

Comment: I still gave me the same  errors apperently, I put it back in Main on top, now I have it in both  C/C++ -> preprocessor -> definitions and in the code, is that a problem?

Comment: @Giraffpaj you don't need to have it in both places, but if you have it in both places it wil work too. I recommend to have it only in one place.

Comment: @Giraffpaj: Note that C++ uses separate compilation. Every .cpp file can cause C4996, so they all need this. Adding it only to the .cpp which defines `int main()` is probably insufficient. But if you use MSVC's precompiled headers, putting it as the first line in the shared, precompiled header does work.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
```

instead.

Answer (score -2):

Do not define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` or other warning suppressions, it is a workaround that is supposed to be used when upgrading code not yet utilizing security enhancements in CRT. Fix the code that is causing them.

Comment: Disagree. The "security enhancements" are Microsoft-proprietary functions, which "coincidentally" make your code non-portable.

Comment: The old functions are not really deprecated, and the new ones are not always seen as an "enhancement". http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm

Comment: @MSalters Utilization of security enhancements in CRT has no impact on portability.